# How to implement Jquery Ajax in success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to implement Jquery Ajax in success in this example?

I click on Getcat is completed. Similar but I click in Cat 1, Cat 2 ... then fail.?

I am sure it is easy but still learning some of the basics here. Thanks

This is **cat.php**

```
<div class="cat">
  <div data-id="4" class="catget">Cat 4</div>

  <div data-id="5" class="catget">Cat 5</div>

  <div data-id="6" class="catget">Cat 6</div>

  <div data-id="7" class="catget">Cat 7</div>

  <div data-id="8" class="catget">Cat 8</div>
</div>
```

This is **index.php**

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> $('.catget').click(function() {
var id = $(this).parent().data('id');
          $.ajax({
            url: 'cat.php',
            data: {
              "id": id
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
              var $response = $(result);
              var cat = $response.filter('.cat').html();
              $('.catsub').html(cat).fadeIn(700);
            }
          });
        });</script>
        <div data-id="1" class="catget">Getcat</div>
        <div class="catsub">Cat List</div>
```

Run Code Snippet.

```js
 $('.catget').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).parent().data('id');
   $.ajax({
     url: 'cat.php',
     data: {
       "id": id
     },
     type: 'post',
     success: function(result) {
       var $response = $(result);
       var cat = $response.filter('.cat').html();
       $('.catsub').html(cat).fadeIn(700);
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-id="1" class="catget">Getcat</div>
<div class="catsub">Cat List</div>
```

Comment: why use `var id = $(this).parent().data('id');` i think you should be using `var id = $(this).attr('data-id');` because `.catget` has the `data-id` not the parent

Comment: you don't need  the `.parent()`... remove it.. it'll look like this... `var id = $(this).data('id');`

Comment: Yes, thanks.
But when **cat.php** returned and replaced in div **catsub** then click does not work.
I am sure it is easy but still learning some of the basics here. Thanks.

Comment: use event delegation for dynamically added elements use `.on()`

Comment: @guradio I think it can not recognize the new **catsub** in  **cat.php** returned and displayed.
How it can recognize new **catsub** in  **cat.php** returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually don't need the parent there since you are getting the id of the children..

here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xojzghfv/

you need something like this for your new element to work.

you can read this for reference purposes: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$(document).on('click', '.catget', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
   //insert the rest of your code here....
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks.
But when **cat.php** returned and replaced in div **catsub** then click does not work.
I am sure it is easy but still learning some of the basics here. Thanks.

Comment: @PVS5011 so you are appending new `subcat`? and it doesn't work when you click it?

Comment: I think it can not recognize the new **catsub** in  **cat.php** returned and displayed.
How it can recognize new **catsub** in  **cat.php** returns

Comment: @PVS5011 lol, did you even try my answer?.... it'll recognize the new appended elements...

Comment: Well I had to follow him, and succeeded. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PVS5011 don't forget to upvote... glad to help you.. =)